# Is it possible to mock more requests types in one test method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-requests

Is it possible to mock more requests types (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT` etc...) in one method? I can mock one type of request with `mock.patch` decorator. But, how can I mock more types in one test method? I am **looking for a Pythonic and elegant solution** for it (I would prefer the `mock.patch` decorator but I am open for other solutions as well).

You can see below an example for my problem:

**source.py**

```
import requests


def source_function():
    x = requests.get("get_url.com")
    requests.post("post_url.com/{}".format(x.text))
```

**test.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from source import source_function


class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch("requests.get")
    def test_source_function(self, mocked_get):
        mocked_get.return_value = mock.Mock(status_code=201, json=lambda: {"data": {"id": "test"}})
        source_function()  # The POST request is not mocked.
```

Comment: You need to patch `source.requests.get`, so the place where the actual call is happening.

Comment: Sure, I do that in production code but it doesn't solve my problem. How can I mock the GET and POST request types in one test method? This is my question.

Comment: You can mock as much as you want. try mocking `post` methods and get an error?

Comment: I can mock GET/POST/PUT etc... separately but I don't know how I should mock more of them in one test method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I only had to pass one-by-one the mock objects.

**source.py**

```
import requests


def source_function():
    x = requests.get("http://get_url.com")
    print("Get resp: {}".format(x.json()))
    y = requests.post("http://post_url.com")
    print("Post resp: {}".format(y.json()))
```

**test.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import source


class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch("source.requests.get")
    @mock.patch("source.requests.post")
    def test_source_function(self, mocked_post, mocked_get):
        mocked_get.return_value = mock.Mock(status_code=200, json=lambda: {"data_get": {"id": "test"}})
        mocked_post.return_value = mock.Mock(status_code=200, json=lambda: {"data_post": {"id": "test"}})
        source.source_function()


# Entry point of script.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
Get resp: {'data_get': {'id': 'test'}}
Post resp: {'data_post': {'id': 'test'}}
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Only the sequence is important. The mock object of the top decorator should be the last one (In my case the `GET` method mock object).